# Real time chat with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So, I have created a simple chat system which consists of nodeJS and mongodb. I currently 'host' it on apache, and it works perfectly on my computer, but if someone else connects to my site on the local network, then the chat doesnt work as intended. The send message and show message function breaks.

Ps: The code is from phpacademy, so cudos to them.

Here's the code I used:

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>ChattSystem</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="chat">
            <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
            <div class="chat-messages"></div>

            <textarea placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
            <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


        <script>
            (function() {
                var getNode = function(s) {
                    return document.querySelector(s);
                },

                // Get required nodes
                status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                messages = getNode('.chat-messages'),
                textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                chatName = getNode('.chat-name');

                statusDefault = status.textContent,

                setStatus = function(s) {
                    status.textContent = s;

                    if(s !== statusDefault) {
                        var delay = setTimeout(function() {
                            setStatus(statusDefault);
                            clearInterval(delay);
                        }, 3000);   
                    }
                };


                try {
                    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                } catch(e) {
                    // Set status to warn user
                }

                if(socket !== undefined) {

                    // Listen for output
                    socket.on('output', function(data) {
                        if(data.length) {
                            // Loop through results
                            for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
                                var message = document.createElement('div');

                                message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ' + data[x].message;

                                // Append
                                messages.appendChild(message);
                                messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    // Listen for a status
                    socket.on('status', function(data) {
                        setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                        if(data.clear === true) {
                            textarea.value = '';
                        }
                    });

                    // Listen for keydown
                    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                        var self = this,
                            name = chatName.value;

                        if(event.which);if(event.which == 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {
                            socket.emit('input', {
                                name: name,
                                message: self.value
                            });

                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });

                }

            })();
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### Server.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    client.on('connection', function(socket) {

        var col = db.collection('messages'),
            sendStatus = function(s) {
                socket.emit('status', s);
            };

        // Emit all messages
        col.find().limit(100).sort({_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, res) {
            if(err) throw err;
            socket.emit('output', res);
        });

        // Wait for input
        socket.on('input', function(data) {
            var name = data.name,
                message = data.message,
                whitespacePattern = /^\s*$/;

            if(whitespacePattern.test(name) || whitespacePattern.test(message)) {
                sendStatus('Name and message is required.');
            } else {
                col.insert({name: name, message: message}, function() {

                    // Emit latest message to ALL qclients
                    client.emit('output', [data]);

                    sendStatus({
                        message: "Message sent",
                        clear: true
                    });
                }); 
            }

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: The issue is that your addresses are hard coded in as localhost (127.0.0.1).  Change those to the correct addresses.

Comment: @TimCooper can we just vote to close. Pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS from client side, change the IP to your server IP..
You script has currently the same local IP, thats mean what is always in localhost...

Find your IP and put it:

**HTML (JS client side)**

```
try {
   var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.x.x:8080');
} catch(e) {
   // Set status to warn user
}
```